# Add Managed Metadata to Person or Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata

I have been trying for quite some time, but have not had any luck. I have on question and one question only.

Is it possible to add managed metadata to people within the Person or Group column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we could not add managed metadata to the Person or Group column.

As referred before, we could only [associate the profile property with a managed metadata term set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/add-and-edit-user-profile-properties) in User profile service application.

For more information, please refer to:

http://www.suhail.cloud/2014/07/map-managed-metadata-term-set-to-user.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own properties to user profiles:

[Add and edit user profile properties in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/add-and-edit-user-profile-properties)